# Netty proxy - how to read http headers

Tags: netty

I am testing netty as proxy server. I have found example:
https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxy.html

However, I want to read HttpHeaders and perform action based on headers, authenticate etc.

I believe that in order to do that, I need to change adapter in frontend to SimpleChannelInboundHandler[HttpObject] or SimpleChannelInboundHandler[Object] and add HttpServerCodec() to pipeline?

However when I do this, I can see that incomming request is translated and I can read DefaultHttpHeaders...
but forward to backend fails.

When I remove HttpServerCodec from pipeline flow is fine.

Can someone say what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **update:** it seems to be failing on outboundCh.writeAndFlush(msg) with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: DefaultHttpRequest (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion)`. But in pipeline there is **following added:**  .addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder())
      .addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder())

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: sure, it is in https://github.com/arempter/s3proxy-netty. It is scala, but really not different from HexDump Java example